# How to click device back button using Selenium, android and C#

Tags: c#, android, selenium, navigation, appium

[image]I am presently running an automation script, I want to click on the device back button, though I have used this snippet `driver.Navigation().back()` previously that worked for clicking app back button. how do click that of the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try below code

```
 driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK); // it will android device back button
```

if you want to perform any other operation with android device keys you can use same approach.You will get keys in **AndroidKeyCode**.

hope these  helps you.

Comment: I'm not using Appium AndroidDriver, using pure Selenium WebDriver for the automation, and Selenium Webdriver does not have an implementation of this method.

Comment: you have to go with AndroidDriver as it provide many such functionality in android device. In  future you will face such issues again so my suggestion is to go with AndroidDriver.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm already on the porting of the code to to use AndroidDriver.